# Is real analysis constructive?

Tags: real-analysis, axiom-of-choice, constructive-mathematics

I'm still wrapping my head around exactly what 'constructive' mathematics is. To my understanding, there are several theorems in real analysis which depend on the axiom of either dependent or countable choice. These are variants of the axiom of choice, and it was shown my Paul Cohen that neither of these axioms are provable in ZF without the axiom of choice. It follows that they have some nonconstructive affiliation, yet, as they are so much weaker than the full axiom of choice, they do not imply the law of excluded middle, and consequently their use in constructive mathematics is not so widely disputed, but what does this say about those methods or theorems in real analysis which do not use these axioms? Is it true that real analysis is "not entirely nonconstructive", and that only certain parts of it are?

Any clarification and responses are appreciated.

Comment: See [Constructive Mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-constructive/) for an introduction with references.

Comment: Maybe useful : D.Bidges, [Introducing Constructive Mathematics](https://www2.masfak.ni.ac.rs/cmfp2013/Nis%20lecture%20170113.pdf).

Comment: Be careful about using 'constructive' to mean 'provable without the axiom of choice'. The axiom of choice is certainly non-constructive, but since ZF is a theory in first-order logic, it admits the law of excluded middle, which is also non-constructive. Are you asking about *constructive* real analysis (i.e. real analysis that can be done in IZF or CZF, for example), or about real analysis without choice?

Comment: @CliveNewstead Before answering that question I should first ask, if ZF admits the law of excluded middle, does that mean that any mathematics that uses ZF is nonconstructive?

Comment: @CliveNewstead Although I'm rather confident I am asking about constructive real analysis.

Comment: @joshuaheckroodt: The law of excluded middle is an axiom of first-order logic, not of ZF itself, but if you work inside ZF then it means you're reasoning using first-order logic, which is not a constructive theory. Proving something using ZF+FOL doesn't necessarily mean the thing you proved can't be proved constructively, though. So it would be more accurate to say that mathematics proved using ZF is 'not *necessarily* constructive'.

Comment: @CliveNewstead Thank you for this. If you don't mind explaining to me in lay terms why it is that $\mathsf{ZF}$ abides by first-order logic?

Comment: A logical theory is built on top of a logical system. The logical system that ZF is built on is first-order logic. ZF doesn't 'abide by' first-order logic, it's simply that ZF is a theory *in* first-order logic. Or put another way, first-order logic is the language used to express the axioms of ZF(C), and gives the logical rules for reasoning about those axioms.

Comment: @CliveNewstead Thank you so much for this clarification. If you'd like to formulate your responses into a comment I'd be happy to tick it.